# If you extend SingletonCachedBizlet, do you need to override the newInstance() method

Tags: skyve

If you are not doing any default values or anything other than using the SingletonCachedBizet to retrieve the singleton record, do you need to override the newInstance() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the default behaviour is inherited and handles retrieving and caching the singleton instance for the document specified in your Bizlet. For example, for a Settings document, this is a sufficient complete definition:

```java
    public class SettingsBizlet extends SingletonCachedBizlet<Settings> {
        // optional depending on your compiler warnings
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7837583728201289659L;
    }
```